# SuiteScript 2.0 search.create returning empty results

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am trying to get all the sales orders which are pending fulfilment at the point of create a new sales order. This is to alert the user that a sales order is already in progress. The code I am using is as such;

```
    function saleOrderInPendingFulfillmentAlreadyExists(scriptContext)
    {
        //Check if the customer already has an order which is pending fulfillment
        debugger;
        var idCustomer = scriptContext.currentRecord.getValue('entity');
        var recCustomer;
        if(idCustomer)
        {
            var filters = [
               ["mainline", "is", "T"], "and",
               ["type", "anyOf", search.Type.SALES_ORDER], "and",
               ["entity", "anyOf", idCustomer],
           ];

           var columns = [ "tranid" ];

           var searchQuery = search.create({
               "type": search.Type.TRANSACTION,
               "filters": filters,
               "columns": columns
           });

           var salesorders = searchQuery.run().getRange({"start": 0, "end": 1000}) || [];

        }
    }
```

When debugging the code, the variable salesorders is an empty array yet I know the customer file has at least 8 Sales Orders on it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `type` search filter expects the record in a different format to the `search.Type` enum (`'SalesOrd'` instead of `'salesorder'`). Welcome to NetSuite!

You can change the filters to

```
var filters = [
   ["mainline", "is", "T"], "and",
   ["type", "anyOf", 'SalesOrd'], "and",
   ["entity", "anyOf", idCustomer],
];
```

or, even better

```
var searchQuery = search.create({
   "type": search.Type.SALES_ORDER,
   "filters": filters,
   "columns": columns
});
```

BTW, you should definitely look into the [NetSuite Search Export Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/netsuite-search-export/gglbgdfbkaelbjpjkiepdmfaihdokglp), which lets you build a search in the UI and converts it automatically to SuiteScript.

Comment: So if I use the second option, does this mean the type filter doesn't need to be there?

Comment: @TomHanson Correct